# What is a good way how to deal with different possible data requests of OData API?

Tags: c#, odata

I have an OData API with one entity and many properties. The user can choose which properties he wants to retrieve from the API. How to best approach this situation of having several possible queries? Say, one user would want to see items of specific weight, another items of specific height, yet another items of both specific weight and height. The properties that they don't specifically request wouldn't be displayed.

The simple and obvious solution would be to write a separate query for each of the possible queries. Is this actually a good approach? E.g., if weight is requested

```
var data = context.MyEntity.Where(e => e.weight == userInputWeight);

foreach(var item in data)
{
  Console.WriteLine("item_name: " + item.name + " weight: " + item.weight);
}
```

and if height is requested

```
var data = context.MyEntity.Where(e => e.height == userInputHeight);

foreach(var item in data)
{
  Console.WriteLine("item_name: " + item.name + " height: " + item.height);
}
```

and so on. Can it be done in a different way, with less repetition of very similar code? I am dealing with 6 possible queries.

Comment: Why is the retrieval of data being treated as a concern of the presentation layer? Why not just retrieve all 6 properties and then let the presentation layer display what the user wants to see?

Comment: @Igor you're right, I should stick with retrieving it all. Is there anything else I can do in a console app about displaying data than just write a separate ```Console.WriteLine``` for each query?